# Find and replace NUL character using VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I have a text file which contains NUL characters in random rows. I want to find first NUL character and delete entire row from that NUL character as in below:

Input:

```
1 2 3 4 20170821NUL20170821NULNULNULNUL 123 NULNULNUL
1 2 3 4 20170821 20170821 6 7 10 123 10 11 13
1 2 3 4 20170821NUL20170821NULNULNULNUL 123 NULNULNUL
1 2 3 4 20170821NUL20170821NULNULNULNUL 123 NULNULNUL
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 20170821
1 2 3 4 20170821 20170821 6 7 10 123 10 11 13
1 2 3 4 20170821
1 2 3 4 20170821
```

I have the following to read text file data to a variable and loop through the data and replace NUL:

```
sInfile = WScript.Arguments(1)

'Create file system object
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFS = oFSO.OpenTextFile(sInfile)
sData = oFS.ReadAll
oFS.Close
Set oFS = Nothing

MsgBox("File Read Completed")

'Remove Rest of the line from NULL
Do While InStr(sData, "\00.*") > 0
    sData = Replace(sData, "\00.*", "")
Loop

'Cleanup and end
Set oFS = Nothing
WScript.Quit
```

The script went passed without any errors but I can't see any changes to the data.

**EDIT 1:**
Updated code:

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Const TriStateUseDefault = -2

If (WScript.Arguments.Count > 0) Then
    sInfile = WScript.Arguments(0)
Else
    WScript.Echo "No filename specified."
    WScript.Quit
End If
If (WScript.Arguments.Count > 1) Then
    sOutfile = WScript.Arguments(1)
Else
    sOutfile = sInfile
End If

'Get the text file from cmd file
sInfile = Wscript.Arguments(1)
' Create file system object
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFS = oFSO.OpenTextFile(sInfile)
sData = oFS.ReadAll
oFS.Close
Set oFS = Nothing

' Remove Rest of the line from NULL
Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = Chr(0) & ".*"
re.Global  = True
sData = re.Replace(sData, "")

Set oOutfile = oFSO.OpenTextFile(sOutfile, ForWriting, True)
oOutfile.Write(sData)
oOutfile.Close
Set oOutfile = Nothing

' Cleanup and end
Set oFS = Nothing
WScript.Quit
```

Here is the sample input I am giving:

[image]

I would like to see the output as below:

[image]

But I got the below output:

```
੊ਊਊਊਊਊਊਊਊਊਊ
```

**EDIT 2:**
I am not aware of hex editors. Here is the sample input of HextDump:

```
FF FE 4A 00 42 00 43 00 09 00 31 00 32 00 33 00 34 00 38 00 36 00 37 00 38 
00 09 00 38 00 37 00 09 00 30 00 09 00 30 00 09 00 31 00 32 00 33 00 09 00 
32 00 30 00 31 00 37 00 09 00 31 00 32 00 33 00 34 00 09 00 31 00 33 00 34 
00 32 00 30 00 09 00 32 00 30 00 31 00 37 00 30 00 38 00 30 00 39 00 09 00 
35 00 31 00 30 00 33 00 09 00 09 00 09 00 09 00 33 00 34 00 31 00 34 00 38 
00 38 00 09 00 32 00 09 00 32 00 30 00 31 00 37 00 09 00 38 00 09 00 31 00 
09 00 37 00 09 00 2D 00 32 00 36 00 34 00 30 00 09 00 2D 00 33 00 39 00 33 
00 2E 00 31 00 36 00 31 00 33 00 37 00 35 00 09 00 2D 00 33 00 33 00 32 00 
2E 00 34 00 36 00 38 00 35 00 37 00 39 00 09 00 41 00 30 00 31 00 31 00 32 
00 35 00 38 00 39 00 2F 00 33 00 34 00 31 00 34 00 38 00 38 00 2F 00 09 00 
09 00 09 00 09 00 09 00 09 00 09 00 09 00 32 00 09 00 09 00 09 00 32 00 31 
00 37 00 38 00 31 00 09 00 58 00 59 00 5A 00 09 00 58 00 59 00 5A 00 09 00 
58 00 59 00 5A 00 09 00 31 00 32 00 33 00 09 00 31 00 32 00 33 00 09 00 2D 
00 32 00 36 00 34 00 09 00 58 00 59 00 5A 00 09 00 31 00 09 00 31 00 09 00 
31 00 32 00 33 00 09 00 09 00 09 00 32 00 31 00 37 00 38 00 32 00 31 00 0D 
00 0A 00 41 00 42 00 43 00 09 00 31 00 32 00 33 00 34 00 38 00 36 00 37 00
```

and the HexDump of output which I got `FF FE 4A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A`

Comment: I asked you to post hexdumps of your sample input and output. Presumably your input file is Unicode-encoded, so I'd like to verify that. Screenshots of the text in your editor are useless. Use a hex-editor like [HxD](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/).

Comment: @S.ai input file encoding is Unicode (it starts with BOM `FF FE`, and you can notice that each char represented in two bytes, with MSB `00`), so you need to specify  [`.OpenTextFile` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/office/gg278834.aspx) forth `format` argument as `-1` while reading the content. Or you may convert encoding using notepad to ANSI and specify `format` as `0`. BTW there is no `NULL` char in the sample.

Comment: Yup, UTF-16 LE, as suspected. See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

The [`Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/238kz954.aspx) function doesn't do regular expression replacements, and VBScript also doesn't recognize `\0` as the character NUL. For the former you need the [`Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9z80300.aspx) method of a regular expression object, for the latter you need the [`Chr`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ws6aa3sf.aspx) function. Also, you don't need a loop, since you read the content of the file as a single string anyway.

However, your file is apparently [UTF-16 LE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) encoded, which means that each character is represented by 2 bytes, one of which is zero for ANSI characters. If you read such files as ANSI files your replacement would remove everything after the first byte. You need to set the 4th parameter of the [`OpenTextFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/314cz14s.aspx) method to -1 in order to handle the file as a UTF-16 (vulgo Unicode) file.

Change this:

```
Set oFS = oFSO.OpenTextFile(sInfile)
sData = oFS.ReadAll
oFS.Close
Set oFS = Nothing
...
Do While InStr(sData, "\00.*") > 0
    sData = Replace(sData, "\00.*", "")
Loop
...
Set oOutfile = oFSO.OpenTextFile(sOutfile, ForWriting, True)
oOutfile.Write(sData)
oOutfile.Close
Set oOutfile = Nothing
```

into this:

```
sData = oFSO.OpenTextFile(sInfile, 1, False, -1).ReadAll

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = Chr(0) & "[^\r\n]*"
re.Global  = True
sData = re.Replace(sData, "")

oFSO.OpenTextFile(sOutfile, 2, True, -1).Write sData
```

and the problem will disappear.

The pattern `[^\r\n]*` (any number of characters that are neither carriage-return nor line-feed) is used to keep Windows line breaks intact. Those consist of the two characters carriage-return and line-feed (CR-LF). The regular expression meta-character `.` does not match line-feeds, but it does match carriage-return, so those would be removed when using the pattern `.*`.

---

For clarity: the above code will remove a NUL character and the remainder of the line from each line containing a NUL character. Lines not containing NUL characters will not be affected.

If you want the entire text after a NUL character removed (including subsequent lines) you could do it like this:

```
Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = Chr(0) & "[\s\S]*"
sData = re.Replace(sData, "")
```

Comment: Thanks @Ansgar I replaced the piece of code as you mentioned in my code and executed but I can't see any changes in the data. `'Get the text file from cmd file
sInfile = Wscript.Arguments(1)
' Create file system object
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFS = oFSO.OpenTextFile(sInfile)
sData = oFS.ReadAll
oFS.Close
Set oFS = Nothing
' Remove Rest of the line from NULL
Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = Chr(0) & ".*"
re.Global  = True
sData = re.Replace(sData, "") 
' Cleanup and end
'Set oFS = Nothing
Wscript.Quit
`-Confused :/

Comment: @S.ai By "can't see any changes in the data" you mean in the file? Well, yes. To see the changes reflected in the file you'd need to actually write the changes back to the file.

Comment: Thanks @Ansgar. I added file writing to the script and I executed the code.. and its boom..  all my data was gone :( and I can see empty text file luckily I have backup file

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to specify regex pattern for `Replace()` function, that won't work. Generally, you don't need to use regex at all.

Here is non-regex code:

```
With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(WScript.Arguments(1), 1, False, 0)
    sData = ""
    If Not .AtEndOfStream Then sData = .ReadAll
    .Close
End With

a = Split(sData, vbCrLf)
For i = 0 To UBound(a)
    q = Instr(a(i), Chr(0))
    If q > 0 Then a(i) = Mid(a(i), 1, q - 1)
Next
sData = Join(a, vbCrLf)
```

And here is regex version:

```
With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(WScript.Arguments(1), 1, False, 0)
    sData = ""
    If Not .AtEndOfStream Then sData = .ReadAll
    .Close
End With

With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    .Pattern = "^(.*?)\x00.*$"
    .Global  = True
    .Multiline  = True
    sData = .Replace(sData, "$1")
End With
```

Comment: Thanks @omegastripes - I tried the both codes non-regex and regex still I am unable to get the required output. After the script execution I can see not even a single change in the data. I don't know what exactly I am missing. I copied the same code and executed.

Comment: @S.ai how do you check result?

Comment: @omegastripes I have created a batch file which will execute the above vbs script and take the required text file as input. While executing the batch file I didn't get any errors. Once the execution done I opened the text file and I can see no changes were applied to text file.

Comment: @omegastripes I can see the changes to text file after writing data to the file. But in this case also I got only these characters as output `੊ਊਊਊਊਊਊ`. All data was erased.